# How to retrieve sql table with all its data using java

Tags: sql, jakarta-ee, glassfish, stateless-session-bean

I am trying to make a **Java EE** project with SQL as my database and  glassfish as my server.
I want to retrieve all the data in my table in to a html page but I have to use **servlet** and **session beans**. My output will be shown in a html page.

Comment: Please tell more that have you done already, better with code samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example

```
<%@ page language="java"%>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.DriverManager"%> 
<%@ page import = "java.sql.ResultSet"%> 
<%@ page import = "java.sql.Statement"%> 
<html>
<body>
<h1>Retrieve data</h1>
<%
try
{
   Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
   Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db", "user", "pass");
   if (!conexion.isClosed())
   {
      Statement st = conexion.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from contact");

      out.println("<table border=\"1\"><tr><td>Id</td>< td>Name</td><td>LastName</td><td>Phone</td></tr>");
      while (rs.next())
      {
         out.println("<tr>");
         out.println("<td>"+rs.getObject("id")+"</td>");
         out.println("<td>"+rs.getObject("Name")+"</td>");
         out.println("<td>"+rs.getObject("LastName")+"</td>");
         out.println("<td>"+rs.getObject("Phone")+"</td>");
         out.println("</tr>");
      }
      out.println("</table>");

      conexion.close();
   }
   else
      out.println("fail");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   out.println("Exception " + e);
   e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks alotbro. thats exactlywhat i waslooking for. i tried on every othe web site. thanks a lot :)

Comment: next query: i have a column in my sql table i want to sum  that column and show it on my html page. the table i am talking about is used for storing billing information. and i would like to give a sum of all the rates. please help.!:)

Comment: This might not be relevant to you right now but it can help someone with the same question. To count, you can simply use the `count` method in mysql. for example `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contacts;` This will give you one value count, I t has worked for me but I stand to be corrected if I have made a mistake.

To sum the values then you can use the `SUM` method for mysql.